# iOS coredata graphical model layout, shows entities on top o each other

Tags: xcode, core-data

So, my CoreData graphical editor style "Graph", was working ok before,

now if I check something on the graphical editor, go to another file, and come back again,
I find all my entities on top of each other... I organise them, go to other file, come back and again on top of each other!

[image: coreData entities mushed up]

So whats going on, how to fix this annoying thing? thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drag the entities away from each other and save the file.